# Tensorflow Serving: InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to prepare my custom Keras model for deploy to be used with Tensorflow Serving, but I'm running into issues with preprocessing my images.

When i train my model i use the following functions to preprocess my images:

```py
def process_image_from_tf_example(self, image_str_tensor, n_channels=3):
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image_str_tensor)
    image.set_shape([256, 256, n_channels])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return image

def read_and_decode(self, serialized):
    parsed_example = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized, features=self.features)
    input_image = self.process_image_from_tf_example(parsed_example["image_raw"], 3)
    ground_truth_image = self.process_image_from_tf_example(parsed_example["gt_image_raw"], 1)
    return input_image, ground_truth_image
```

My images are PNGs saved locally, and when i write them on the `.tfrecord` files i use 
`tf.gfile.GFile(str(image_path), 'rb').read()`

This works, I'm able to train my model and use it for local predictions.

Now I want to deploy my model to be used with Tensorflow Serving. My `serving_input_receiver_fn` function looks like this:

```py
def serving_input_receiver_fn(self):
    input_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='image_bytes')
    images_tensor = tf.map_fn(self.process_image_from_tf_example, input_ph, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver({'input_1': images_tensor}, {'image_bytes': input_ph})
```

where `process_image_from_tf_example` is the same function as above, but i get the following error:

`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]`

Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687348/decoding-tfrecord-with-tfslim) it looks like this error is due to the fact that i'm not using 
`tf.gfile.GFile(str(image_path), 'rb').read()`

as with my training/test files, but i can't use it because i need to send encoded bytes formatted as

`{"image_bytes": {'b64': base64.b64encode(image).decode()}}`

as requested by TF Serving.

[Examples online](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/r1.11/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py#L172) send JPEG encoded bytes and preprocess the image starting with

`tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)`

but if i use a different preprocessing function in my `serving_input_receiver_fn` (different than the one used for training) that starts with

`tf.image.decode_png(image_buffer, channels=3)`

i get the following error:

`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'`

(the same happens with `decode_jpeg`, by the way)

What am i doing wrong? Do you need more code from me to answer? Thanks a lot!

**Edit!!**
Changed the title because it was not clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I solved it.

`image` was a numpy array but i had to do the following:

```py
buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1].tostring()
bytes_image = base64.b64encode(buffer).decode('ascii')
{"image_bytes": {"b64": bytes_image}}
```

Also, my preprocessing and `serving_input_receiver_fn` functions changed:

```py
def process_image_from_buffer(self, image_buffer):
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(image, [256, 256], align_corners=False)
    image = tf.squeeze(image, [0])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255.0
    return image

def serving_input_receiver_fn(self):
    input_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])
    images_tensor = tf.map_fn(self.process_image_from_buffer, input_ph, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver({'input_1': images_tensor}, {'image_bytes': input_ph})
```

`process_image_from_buffer` is different than `process_image_from_tf_example` used above for training. 
I also removed `name='image_bytes'` from `input_ph` above.

Hope it's clear enough to help someone else.

[Excellent guide partially used for solving it](https://github.com/mhwilder/tf-keras-gcloud-deployment/)